# Configure Linphone Desktop to use same SIP for all users in Windows

Tags: configuration, sip, linphone

I am experimenting with my first time setup of a Linphone 5.2.1 on a Windows PC in a conference room as a softphone and have the phone working.  As this PC is used by many different users, they must setup the SIP info the first time they log onto the system or if their profile was removed since their last use.  Is there a means to set the SIP inforamtion at the application and not the user level?  I see a reference to "use_app_sip_account_enabled" in the linphonerc file but cannot find any additional inforamtion.  Also is there a good reference source for the apps parameters?  I found GitHub reposatory and wiki.linphone.org but no real details as to the configuration options.

I did find if I copy the C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\linphone\linphonerc file from a configured users profile into the apps C:\Program Files\Linphone\share\linphone\linphonerc-factory file, the parameters apear to copy to each users setting on first logon and work without issues.  It is the same device so there are no hardware changes.  Is this a valid option?  I am experimeting with paring down what is copied to just a subset of parimeters such as [SIP], [proxy_0] and [auth_info_0].  However, this does not work.  What parameters are needed for the SIP config?